# KSQLDB REGEXP_REPLACE not found

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Weirdest thing, I am getting an error when attempting

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(user_id, 'a.b+', 'bar')
```

> Can't find any functions with the name 'REGEXP_REPLACE'

but this works

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT('(([aeiouAEIOU]).)', user_id, 2)
```

both are directly from https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/scalar-functions/#replace

using latest ksqldb server docker image.

Comment: Weird! Can you provide the full SQL to recreate, and the full error messages, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`REGEXP_EXTRACT` was added to ksqlDB in version 0.8, where as `REGEXP_REPLACE` was not added until version 0.10.

If you're getting a function not found error, then I'm guessing you'll need to upgrade your ksqlDB version.

Comment: Coates for the win, Unbeknownst to me Docker was using cache (0.9) but then I had to deal with my scripts not working with v0.11. but got those issues working now.